# Getting class name of last child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to retrieve the class name of the last child element in `.find_class`, but my code gives me `undefined`. How can I fix it?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gBxan/

```
<div class="find_class">
    <div class="class1"></div>
    <div class="class2"></div>
    <div class="class3"></div> <!-- I want to get this div's class name -->
</div>

var find = $('div.find_class div:last').find('div:last').attr('class');
alert(find);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to lose the extra `find`:

```
var cls = $('div.find_class div:last').attr('class');
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/YVK3R/)**.

Comment: bingo! also not a bad idea to add `>`

Answer (score 0):

maybe the following code will do the job:

```
var divs = $(".find_class").find("div");
var lastDiv = divs.eq(divs.length-1);
alert(lastDiv.attr("class"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example in the question is slightly different than your example in the replies.  You only want to be looking at the immediate child divs.

Try this:

```
var find = $('div.find_class > div:last').attr('class');
alert(find);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/VbxpY/